# How to set sound volume to 0 in IFrame?

Tags: iframe, audio, set, volume

I have the following line in my Html file, which displays a video feed, how do I set sound volume to 0 in IFrame ? So that when the page is first loaded, there is no sound.

```
<iframe src="http://onionz.co.cc/ain.php?psid=1626397" id="player" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" align="center" Width=588 Height=351></iframe>
```

Is there a paremeter like "volume=0" in IFrame that I can set ?

Comment: As of 2021, this is not currently possible for cross-domain/third-party iframe. If you want it to be supported, staring [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=985312) may help Chromium contributors gauge interest. If you have a specific use case, you can also leave a comment on that issue (but please don't comment simple/unhelpful things like "I need this!" - just star it instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that's possible. You could silence the systems volume, or the process volume at most.
But that would mute the whole browser, not just the iframe!.

What you may be able to do is use javascript to manipulate the videofeed and silence it, but not the iframe as your requesting.

Comment: Correct. No current-version browser can mute on a per-frame basis.

Comment: How to use javascript to manipulate the videofeed and silence it, any sample code ?